# Unicode displaying strange in Edge

Tags: html, css, unicode, microsoft-edge

What I want it to look like:

[image: Expected]

What it looks like in Edge:

[image: Actual]

The Unicode character is ▶

I am assuming edge is just trying to be clever and displaying their own image for my unicode character. How do I prevnt this nonesense. I have googled with no avail.

Comment: When you write Unicode characters, please add also the Unicode codepoint number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find some insight in this [thread](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11635143/). As it turns out, there is a workaround, but you would need to change the `font-family`, at least for your symbol (assuming that you wrap your icon in `<span>` element with `icon` class) :

```
.icon {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I read that thread but turns out I missed that comment.