# Pseudo Selector Color Changes to Blue in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css-selectors, microsoft-edge

[image]I've been facing a strange problem in Microsoft Edge, I'm using Pseudo Selector :after to add an arrow to all the links in a paragraph but Microsoft Edge automatically changes the color to BLUE and above that you cannot even access the Pseudo Selector in Edge.

At first I thought, it was some theme styles, I set up a small html page with 1 link and Pseudo Selector but it changes color to blue here as well but works fine everywhere even in Internet Explorer!

Any help would be great.

No one seems to be facing this problem, I've searched some of the blogs.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <style>
            a{
                color: rgba(51,51,51,1) !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }
            a:before{
                content: "\25B6" !important;
                padding-right: 10px;
                color: rgba(51,51,51,1) !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }
        </style>

        <a href="#">Some Link</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try setting color value as hex value: #515151 ?

Comment: Hi, yes tried with both RGBA & Hex as well. 
Update: Added Screenshot & Code.

Comment: Could see the issue. Seems to he related to content symbol. If you set just a teststring it works

Comment: Thanks. This one and the answer below both worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is already answered in an other post:
[Unicode displaying strange in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277837/unicode-displaying-strange-in-edge)

Setting the font-family to:

```
font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
```

seems to do the trick.